# Java: Program to allow people through a Gate

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, reentrantlock

I am writing a program to do a gate count of 5, and then allow people into the building (by doing a System.out.println).

I have the following solution, using synchronized. However, someone mentioned this solution does not allow for sequential lock fairness, for people in line. How can I rewrite this to allow for it? Is semaphores below correct?

**Using Synchronized:**

```
public class LineCount {

    int totalInLine = 0;

    public synchronized void addToLine() {
        totalInLine = totalInLine + 1;
        if (totalInLine == 5) {
             System.out.println("People may enter");
             totalInLine = 0;
        }
    }
```

**Using Semaphore:**

```
public class LineCount {

    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5, true);

    public void addToLine() throws InterruptedException {

        semaphore.acquire();
        if (semaphore.availablePermits() == 0) {
            System.out.println("People may enter");
            semaphore.release(5);
            semaphore = new Semaphore(5, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I want to print it on the 5th call, and reset and repeat,   apologize, I fixed the semaphore code to semaphore.availablePermits() == 0 @SolomonSlow

Comment: I think second one ensures for sequential fairness, writing tests right now, thanks @SolomonSlow

Comment: hi @SolomonSlow thanks, can you write updated code? and I can send points, let me try it in my ide also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Semaphore` version is almost, but not quite the same as the `synchronized` version. But, the `Semaphore` version isn't thread safe. I suggest two changes:

```java
public class LineCount {

    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5, true);   // added `final` keyword

    public void addToLine() throws InterruptedException {
        semaphore.acquire();
        if (semaphore.availablePermits() == 0) {
            System.out.println("People may enter");
            semaphore.release(5);
         // semaphore = new Semaphore(5, true);           // **Don't Do This**
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is, if some thread A executes the `semaphore.release(5)` statement, then thread B could slip in, and decrement the *old* Semaphore before thread A's `semaphore = new Semaphore(...)` assignment takes effect. That would allow more than five calls before the next time the message is printed.

There is no need to create a new Semaphore because each `release(5)` call will allow five more calls to acquire a permit.

The reason for `final` is mostly just to make sure that everybody who reads the code will immediately understand that `semaphore` always will refer to the same object.

---

**Update:**

> However, someone mentioned [that the `synchronized`] solution does not allow for sequential lock fairness, for people in line.

I can't even guess what that means. You should ask "someone" for clarity.

Your `synchronized` version of `addToLine` prints a message on every fifth call. It doesn't do anything else. It doesn't make any caller *wait* for any longer than it takes some other caller to print the message. Where is the "unfairness" in that?

The title of your question is "Program to allow people through a gate." But there's nothing here that really models a gate. There's nothing in it that makes any "person" *wait* for the "gate" to "open." It's literally just a thread-safe method that prints a certain message on every fifth call.

Comment: hi , I was reading about lock fairness with synchronized here, https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-locks#:~:text=We%20can%20have%20Lock%20APIs,by%20specifying%20the%20fairness%20property.          "A synchronized block doesn’t support the fairness. Any thread can acquire the lock once released, and no preference can be specified"

Comment: @mattsmith5, I know what lock fairness is, but I don't see how it pertains to your program except maybe, in the case where there are thousands of threads, and they're calling `addToLine` faster than the "People may enter" messages can be printed. But if that's the case, then you've probably got bigger problems than just "fairness." As a general rule, if you think you need a mutex (or a semaphore that's being used _as_ a mutex) to be "fair," then there's probably a design flaw in your code. "Fairness" is no advantage if the mutex is not heavily contested.